# Why does strptime behave differently in Rails' test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to parse the date `2/31/2019`, which should raise an error.

In the Rails console this works as expected in development mode, but my tests are failing in test mode because it returns `March 3, 2019`.

```
Date.strptime("2/31/2019", "%m/%d/%Y") #=> dev env: error
Date.strptime("2/31/2019", "%m/%d/%Y") #=> test env: “Sun, 03 Mar 2019”
```

The commands I'm using are:

```
rails c
RAILS_ENV=test rails c
rspec <filename>
```

I'm using Ruby 2.3.1 and Rails 5.0.6.

Comment: Do you use `timecop` gem?

Comment: @MarekLipka Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timecop overwrites the `Date.strptime` definition:

```
[4] pry(main)> puts Date.method(:strptime).source
def strptime_with_mock_date(str = '-4712-01-01', fmt = '%F', start = Date::ITALY)
  unless start == Date::ITALY
    raise ArgumentError, "Timecop's #{self}::#{__method__} only " +
      "supports Date::ITALY for the start argument."
  end

  Time.strptime(str, fmt).to_date
end
```

That's why the output is different between environments, since Timecop is only required in test.

Comment: Any way I can get it to fail like it should in test?

Comment: I don't know. It seems it's known issue with `timecop`: 

https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop/issues/116

Comment: It may have been fixed recently but I'm locked into this environment https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop/pull/115